# How to prove the following modulo equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $$ p=a^{2}+64b^{2},\:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$$  is a prime number. Prove that $$ 2^{(p^{2}-1)/4}\equiv1\:\left(mod\:p\right)$$

Comment: Most likely related : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $p\equiv a^2\equiv 1 \pmod 8$,  $2$ is a quadratic residue modules $p$. 
As a result $2^{\frac{p^2-1}8}\equiv 2^{\frac{p-1}{2}\cdot\frac{p+1}2}\equiv 1^{\frac{p+1}2}\equiv 1\pmod p$

Answer (score 1):

A bit of culture, Gauss proved that a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ can be written as $p = x^2 + 64 y^2$ if and only if $2$ is a fourth power $\pmod p.$ That is, if and only if there is some integer $t \neq 0 \pmod p$ such that
$$ t^4 \equiv 2 \pmod p. $$

For your problem, you can reduce the exponent to $(p-1)/ 4,$ as
$$ 2^{(p-1)/ 4} \equiv \left( t^4 \right)^{(p-1)/ 4} \equiv t^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p. $$

The first few such primes (ignore the initial $1$) are

```
      1,     73,     89,    113,    233,    257,    281,    337,    353,    577,
    593,    601,    617,    881,    937,   1033,   1049,   1097,   1153,   1193,
   1201,   1217,   1249,   1289,   1433,   1481,   1553,   1601,   1609,   1721,
   1753,   1777,   1801,   1889,   1913,
```

For example, $18^4 \equiv 2 \pmod {73}.$  $5^4 \equiv 2 \pmod {89}.$  $27^4 \equiv 2 \pmod {113}.$

Answer (score 0):

First observe that $p \neq 2$. If $p=2$ then $a^2 \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and so $a^2$ and hence $a$ must be divisible by 2. But that implies that $a^2$ is divisble by 4 and since $64b^2$ also is, $p$ must be divisble by 4 and cannot be equal to 2.

Now use a consequence of Fermat's little theorem that says that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for a prime $p$ and a number $a$ that is not divisble by $p$ and rewrite the expression:

$2^{\frac{p^2-1}{4}}=(2^{p-1})^{\frac{p+1}{4}}\equiv 1^{\frac{p+1}{4}}=1 \mod p.$

Comment: $$p+1\equiv2\:(mod\:4)$$ therefore $$\dfrac{p+1}{4}\notin\mathbb{Z}$$